# SQL: Best way to perform Update record operation to any given MySQL table

Tags: sql

im programming a app to perform CRUD to any given table in any given database (MySQL).

Im having trouble figuring the best way to deal with the Update operation.

I was thinking: 1)Find Primary Key on table & 2)Update record according to Primary Key field coincidence between both records (incoming and allready present in MySQL table).

I know that while Primary Key in every table is very suggested it is still optional, so as i said im not sure if theres a better aproach since my method would not work with a table without a Primary Key.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Whats do you need that for? How big is your application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer i found that i believe is valid is the following: For the Update action send two records to the server, the non updated one and the updated one.

The server side has to include each field of the non-updated record in the where clause of the update query with LIMIT=1 (to avoid problems with duplicated records).